# Wordpress: wp_enqueue_style not working

Tags: php, css, wordpress, media-queries

I see that others have had problems with this function in more particular cases, but I really am just having trouble getting it to work at all.

I have this in my `functions.php`:

```
function load_styles() {
    wp_register_style( 'style', get_stylesheet_uri() );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'style' );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'load_styles' );
```

This has no effect on the styling of my site. It works if I put this in `header.php` instead:

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo get_stylesheet_uri(); ?>" />`

I would just go with the latter, then (even though I know it's not technically proper), but for some reason my media queries aren't working that way so I thought I would try to enqueue the styles properly. I'm totally at a loss here; any suggestions greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you, or is your theme enqueuing other stylesheets? Try changing the handle in your function and see if anything changes.

Comment: No other styles used. Tried changing the handle and it didn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should just be able to enqueue your theme's style without registering it first.

```
wp_enqueue_style('style', get_stylesheet_uri(), []);
```

If that still doesn't work, check that your `header.php` includes `wp_head();` as that outputs the enqueued styles.

Comment: The issue was that I was missing `wp_head()`. Thanks so much, somehow none of the documentation I saw told me I needed that.

Comment: Don't forget your `wp_footer();` too. ;-)  Without it, you may experience difficulties with the WordPress Dashboard/Tool Bar. :-)